# Start and End Dates with Datepicker jQuery and Gravity Forms

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, datepicker, gravity

I have a form with Gravity Forms in WordPress, this form has 2 datepickers: Check-in date and Check-out Date, but I want that when the costumer selects a date in the check-in date, automatically the check-out date updates with a day after the check-in date, so, this is what i have done with no result:

First I added a function in my `functions.php` from my theme:

```
/**
* Gravity Forms Datepicker Changes
*/
function my_scripts_method() {
   wp_register_script( 'my-js-file',
       get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-js.js',
       array( 'jquery' ),
       '1.0',
       false );

   wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js-file' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

Then I created a folder in my theme called `/js` and also i created a file called `my-js.js`, in which I have this code:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function ($)) {
    $('#input_7_1').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            $('#input_7_5').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);
        }
    });

    $('#input_7_5').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            $('#input_7_1').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

But the problem is that there is no effect in my datepickers, nothing changes, any idea why is this happening?

There is another weird thing, if gravity forms have this file: `datepicker.js` and if i delete everything there, nothing changes, or if change some value, also there are no changes. this is the code inside that file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(gformInitDatepicker);
function gformInitDatepicker(){
    jQuery('.datepicker').each(
        function (){
            var element = jQuery(this);
            var format = "mm/dd/yy";

            if(element.hasClass("mdy"))
                format = "mm/dd/yy";
            else if(element.hasClass("dmy"))
                format = "dd/mm/yy";
            else if(element.hasClass("dmy_dash"))
                format = "dd-mm-yy";
            else if(element.hasClass("dmy_dot"))
                format = "dd.mm.yy";
            else if(element.hasClass("ymd_slash"))
                format = "yy/mm/dd";
            else if(element.hasClass("ymd_dash"))
                format = "yy-mm-dd";
            else if(element.hasClass("ymd_dot"))
                format = "yy.mm.dd";

            var image = "";
            var showOn = "focus";
            if(element.hasClass("datepicker_with_icon")){
                showOn = "both";
                image = jQuery('#gforms_calendar_icon_' + this.id).val();
            }

            element.datepicker({ yearRange: '-100:+20', minDate: +10, maxDate: "+24M +30D", showOn: showOn, buttonImage: image, buttonImageOnly: true, dateFormat: format,  changeMonth: false, changeYear: false, showAnim: 'slideDown', duration: 'slow' }).attr('readonly','readonly');
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: could be the other datepicker code is running after yours

Comment: so, how can i make sure about this?, there is a file in gravity forms plugin where other code is applied to all datepickers

Comment: look in the page source and see if it's true first. Might also need to use `destroy` method before declaring new settings. Or just pass new options in and don't initialize them if they are already initialized

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to use the destroy method?

Comment: `$('#input_7_1').datepicker('destroy');`

Comment: Is the datepicker popping up? Make sure to enqueue the datepicker and ui as well.

`wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );`
`wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-css', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');`

Comment: Yes, and also im using the datepicker in a modal box

Comment: i made the change with your code, and also the destroy function, but nothing changes.

Comment: There is another weird thing, if gravity forms have this file: `datepicker.js`

Comment: Please, mark an answer as correct instead of adding `Solved` to the title. Check the site **[tour]**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out at the end, and i would like to share the solution:

For some reason i wasn´t able to use the code in the way i tried, so the code in functions.php of my theme in wordpress doesn´t work, but i tried with another code inserting this on my page.php of my theme, and it worked, also i had to change every "$" to "jQuery", so the code worked in that way, this is the code i used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_render', function(){
        // destroy default Gravity Form datepicker
jQuery("#input_7_1").datepicker('destroy');
        // create new custom datepicker
jQuery('#input_7_1').datepicker({
    minDate: 1,
    defaultDate: 0,
    dateFormat: "m/d/yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
        var d = jQuery.datepicker.parseDate(inst.settings.dateFormat, dateText);
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
        jQuery('#input_7_5').val(jQuery.datepicker.formatDate(inst.settings.dateFormat, d));
        jQuery('#input_7_5').datepicker('option', {
            minDate: jQuery.datepicker.formatDate(inst.settings.dateFormat, d)
        });
    }
});
// destroy default Gravity Form datepicker
jQuery('#input_7_5').datepicker('destroy');
jQuery('#input_7_5').datepicker({
    minDate: "d",
    defaultDate: "d",
    dateFormat: "m/d/yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: false,
});
})
</script>
```

Hope this help anyone else trying to change something from the jquery datepicker of gravity forms.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is a rather old post, but for those that stumble upon the same issue, the issue doesn't require such a complex solution - all that was missing was the "refresh:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function ($)) {
    $('#input_7_1').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            $('#input_7_5').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);
            $('#input_7_5').datepicker('refresh');
        }
    });

    $('#input_7_5').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            $('#input_7_1').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', selectedDate);
            $('#input_7_1').datepicker('refresh');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to fuss with code, I wrote a plugin that will handle this from within the Gravity Forms UI.

http://gravitywiz.com/how-to-restrict-dates-in-second-date-field-based-on-date-selected-in-first-date-field-with-gravity-forms/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using setDate, see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enriqg9/4m2Xp/).

```
$(function() {
  $( "#from" ).datepicker({
     onSelect: function () {
         var newDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); 
         newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate()+7); 
         $('#to').datepicker('setDate', newDate);
     }
  });

  $( "#to" ).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is that for some reason any change is taking no effect, im not sure why, can i add this code to datepicker.js in gravity forms folder?, or do i have to add the function to my theme functions?

Comment: @user55125 Add it wherever the datepicker code is, I believe that you mention that it is `my-js.js`.

Comment: yes, i did it, but there are no changes at all, even if i change the main datepicker.js from gravityforms plugin folder, this is weird, because i changed before some months ago, but now there are no effects on nothing, i already tried purgin cache, cloudflare, in development mode, but nothing.

Comment: @user55125 Is the HTML of the form matching the HTML in the fiddle? Make sure to adjust the code to whatever your form is.

Comment: It is, all this is done by gravity forms plugin, and i check already the datepickers id´s, and it matches as it should be.

Comment: @user55125 What is the link to your form?

Comment: I cant sincero my site os under comming soon Mode, ill try ti check  a couple of things and ill be back

Answer (score 0):

Your code works and I'm using it on my website, but I had one issue that I found a way to fix it.

The problem was that when you click on the input field the first time, the datepicker shows up just fine. But if you don't pick a date and click anywhere else on page, when you click on the input field again the datepicker don't show up anymore. The fix for that was to change the **onClose** event to **onSelect**. I'm a noob so I'm don't know what causes the issue but I got it working now.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_render', function(){
jQuery(".event_date_value input").datepicker('destroy');
jQuery('.event_date_value input').datepicker({
    minDate: 1,
    defaultDate: 0,
    dateFormat: "m/d/yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        var d = jQuery.datepicker.parseDate(inst.settings.dateFormat, dateText);
        d.setDate(d.getDate() - 30);
        jQuery('.balance_date_value  input').val(jQuery.datepicker.formatDate(inst.settings.dateFormat, d));
    jQuery('.balance_date_value input').datepicker('option', {
        minDate: jQuery.datepicker.formatDate(inst.settings.dateFormat, d)
    });
}
});

jQuery('.balance_date_value input').datepicker('destroy');
jQuery('.balance_date_value input').datepicker({
    minDate: "d",
    defaultDate: "d",
    dateFormat: "m/d/yy",
    changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: false,
});
})
</script>`
```

Comment: For a more complete answer, could you post the modified portion of the code?

Comment: Actually Onselect function for me gives me another error, wich is that the datepicker automaticly opens the second datepicker(check-out), but is a bit confusing, i think the best we can do, is make the field blocked, i mean making the field read only, in that way the datepicker will always open, without error, i will try to do it and when done, ill post the result and code to do. :)

Answer (score 0):

Gravity forms documents this scenario and provides a solution. They call it "Datepicker 1 becomes minDate for datepicker 2". Add some js to your page containing the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
gform.addFilter( 'gform_datepicker_options_pre_init', function( optionsObj, formId, fieldId ) {
    if ( formId == 7 && fieldId == 1 ) {
        optionsObj.minDate = 0;
        optionsObj.onClose = function (dateText, inst) {
             jQuery('#input_7_5').datepicker('option', 'minDate', dateText).datepicker('setDate', dateText);
        };
    }
    return optionsObj;
});
</script>
```